# ANTLR 4.7.1: C++ code in antlr4-runtime with incorrect paths for includes, possibly due to incorrect includePath in .vscode

Tags: c++, antlr4, visual-studio-code, include-path

When [downloading](https://www.antlr.org/download/) (C++, Windows), the files contained within have directories which are not always relative to the file, for example `antlr4-runtime/atn/AbstractPredicateTransition.h` contains `#include "atn/Transition.h"` which fails unless I remove the `atn/`. This occurs for a lot of the files.

Sometimes the files contain both correct and incorrect includes, for example here, where both header files are in the same directory as the file, so only the bottom one is correct:

```
#include "atn/AbstractPredicateTransition.h"
#include "SemanticContext.h"
```

Should be:

```
#include "AbstractPredicateTransition.h"
#include "SemanticContext.h"
```

(`antlr4-runtime\atn\PrecedencePredicateTransition.h`)

I have tried to resolve this by creating a new `.vscode` folder in the same directory and adding a `c_cpp_properties.json` file with the following text (I don't know if anything other than the `includePath` is necessary but I've put it in anyway just in case):

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "antlr4-runtime",
            "antlr4-runtime/atn",
            "antlr4-runtime/dfa",
            "antlr4-runtime/misc",
            "antlr4-runtime/support",
            "antlr4-runtime/tree"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Auxiliary/VS/include/*",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        },
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Note: Despite having a path to Visual Studio, I am using Visual Studio **Code**.

I have tried various different lists for `includePath` such as just `["${workspaceFolder}", "antlr4-runtime"]` and putting `antlr4-runtime in a different folder higher up`. However, it still gives me the same error that there are invalid include paths.

It seems that if I can make the files try to include from the `antlr4-runtime` folder to begin with, then all of the includes will be valid since it seems that all of the includes are relative to inside that folder.

In the screenshot, I'm trying to do a 'hello world' by parsing JSON.

In `Driver.cpp`, the following includes are contained:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "JSONLexer.h"
#include "JSONParser.h"
#include "antlr4-runtime/JSONVisitor.h"
```

(None of these have red squiggly lines underneath)

There are various JSON-related files in the `antlr4-runtime` folder but the rest of it is downloaded from [here](https://www.antlr.org/download/) (4.7.1 for Windows).

[image: File structure in Visual Studio Code]

Answer (score 0):

VSCode C++ is implemented by an LSP server, which likely needs build files to make sense of everything. Cpp and h files do not make a program--never had. That's why Make was invented. It's unclear what build file you have (nothing is listed in your picture). Knowing how LSP works (I'm writing an Antlr LSP server), I wouldn't expect VSCode to forward those settings down to the LSP server for builds. So, yes, I would expect the server to flag those #includes. Seeing this missing, I decided to make a Windows Antlr C++ program using CMake. The program builds and runs fine in VSCode. And I was able to add #include "atn/AbstractPredicateTransition.h" to a source, "Go to Definition" to that include, and the file that it includes. VSCode had no red squiggly lines for any of the #include lines. You could probably change the "include_directories" macro to include Antlr runtime subdirectories, but I haven't tried, and I would likely leave the "atn/" prefix in the #includes. I used Antlr4.8, CMake, and the instructions to set it up described [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp/cmake). The code I wrote is [here](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/CMakeProject1). It also works fine in VS2019.